# Read property from file and assign to a different name in ant?

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to read a property from properties file and assign to a different name but it is not working. I am new to ant so I guess I am missing something basic.

**build.properties:**

```
USERNAME=deter_dangler
```

**build.xml:**

```
<project name="Simple Ant example" default="test" basedir=".">
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="uname" value="${env.USERNAME}"/>
    <target name="test">
        <echo message="uname property value is ${uname}"/>
        <echo message="env.USERNAME property value is ${env.USERNAME}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

The output when I run the build command:

```
javanoob@DELL:~/Desktop$ ant 
Buildfile: /Desktop/build.xml

test:
     [echo] uname property value is ${env.USERNAME}
     [echo] env.USERNAME property value is ${env.USERNAME}

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying setting the environment variable as follows:

```
USERNAME=deter_dangler ant
```

Alternatively, if you want to use a properties file then simplify your ANT file as follows:

```
<project name="Simple Ant example" default="test" basedir=".">
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <target name="test">
        <echo message="uname property value is ${USERNAME}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I modified the property file as you mentioned but still same result.  The alternative approach works but I am just interested in knowing what is wrong with my code.

Comment: @javanoob In your code you're printing an unset environment variable. The alternative code is working because it's accessing the property set in the imported property file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it could be simple incorrect environment variable being used i.e., by default `USER` is available on the linux machine without requiring to be explicitly defined by user and you are using `USERNAME`. I assume this is what user is expecting as he is trying to print value from property and another one from system defined default.

So, just replacing the above mentioned changes in the `build.properties` and `build.xml` files.

**build.properties**

```properties
USER=deter_dangler
```

**build.xml**

```xml
<project name="Simple Ant example" default="test" basedir=".">
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="uname" value="${USER}"/>
    <target name="test">
        <echo message="uname property value is ${uname}"/>
        <echo message="env.USER property value is ${env.USER}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

**Output**

```html
Buildfile: /home/apps/Documents/so/34553709/build.xml

test:
     [echo] uname property value is deter_dangler
     [echo] env.USER property value is apps

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

In the above, if you notice, `${USER}` is taken from *property file* and `${env.USER}` from system logged in user.